# What framework do referenced dlls run under?

Tags: .net

I have an application that references a dll built in .Net Framework 4.5

The dll [an sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MYOB.AccountRight.API.SDK/2016.2.99) that calls an API.

The API is ending support for TLS1.0 and so I am trying to understand what I need to do. [as explained here](http://myobapi.tumblr.com/post/177017431449/tls10-no-longer-supported)

In a solution where the .exe is using a later framework ( say 4.6.1 )

which framework will the code in the dll run under?

I always assumed it would be the dll's framework since that is what it was built under.  However it is explained to me [here](https://community.myob.com/t5/MYOB-API-questions-and-answers/Ending-TLS1-0-support-for-MYOB-API/m-p/541749#M3469)

> "The SDK is included in your application code - therefore it relies on
>   the frameworks you are using"

and seek further clarification.

Comment: Your citation is a bit out of context, who has told you that? Usually your app runs using the framework installed on the target machine. And if this framework is a more recent version it is compatible with the previous version. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility

Comment: Probably this means: _Their SDK is included in YOUR application code, therefore it relies on the NET framework you are using_

Comment: @HansPassant does that mean if my client is running Windows 10 they will be using TLS1.2 ?

Comment: @Steve, thanks for your comments I updated the question to give better context.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls Microsoft made a few tough choices, so in your case, the target framework version your assemblies compile against matters, which you didn't make clear above. Please run a few experiments, and use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the handshakes. Then you can study the behaviors and understand the best practices article better.